Difference between 察す, 察する and 推測する

別に天才でなくとも察しはつきます。
Even if I'm not a genius I can make a guess.

I am assuming that 察しはつく is 察し + は + つく. Would I be correct to think that 察し is a noun meaning "guess", rather than the masu-stem of 察す, and that  察しはつく literally means "attach a guess", i.e. "make a guess"?
While looking up 察す I also came across 察する. I saw in  this post that 察する means "to notice/understand/guess (some fact, indirectly via a circumstantial evidence, a facial expression, etc)". How does this word differ from 察す? Furthermore, how do they both differ from 推測する, which is the only word I knew up until now.

The difference between 察する (suru-verb) and 察す (godan) is the same as that between 愛する and 愛す, 制する and 制す, 罰する and 罰す, etc.

Conjugations of [single-on'yomi-kanji] + する verbs are unstable due to the lingering influence from Classical Japanese. In short, there are two variants (五段/consonant-stem and サ変/suru-stem) of the same verb always coexist.

In the case of 察す(る), the suru-verb version is predominant, and you probably never need to use 察す yourself (e.g., 察しない is much more common than 察さない). As shown in the linked table, 察し is the masu-stem of both verbs, so it may not make much sense to strictly determine which is the base verb before nominalization.
推測 (inference/deduction) is something you do based on evidence, knowledge, and logical reasoning. On the other hand, 察する is more of a social skill; it's something you do intuitively, typically based on someone's mood, tone of writing, or facial expression. For example, 察する is used when you sense someone is hiding something, or when you realize it's time to leave before being explicitly told.
お察しください is an expression commonly used when the speaker wants to avoid explicitly stating something. It's like "(I'd rather not elaborate but) please understand my situation".
