Why is the potential form of 察する not 察できる?
自分一人では何も察せられない。明日白日の下で真意を聞き取りたい...
The character got told something confusing and, as far as I can tell, he says "No point, I can't figure this out on my own. I'll just ask them tomorrow"
https://cooljugator.com/ja/%E5%AF%9F%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B
察せられない is, as far as I can tell, the potential form of 察する. However, why is it not written as 察できる?

https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/5113, https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/46857, https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/56257, https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/106362

さっできる seems awkward

@Leebo presumably it would revert to さつできる, since the use of っ is basically a contraction that only makes sense before certain consonants.
